# Почему вместо изображения белый экран?

Tags: python, изображения, kivy

Пишу программу на Kivy, и решил поставить картинку на фон, вот только вместо неё белый экран. Не подскажете в чем речь если что, изображение в одной папке с файлом .py, буду благодарен!

Вот код:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

from kivy.config import Config

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.metrics import dp

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

Config.set("graphics", "resizable", "0")
Config.set("graphics", "width", "450")
Config.set("graphics", "height", "750")

Builder.load_string(
"""
<Menu>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: [10]
        spacing: 5
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: "Gradient.png"
    
        Label:
            text: ""
            size_hint: [1, 0.4]
        Button:
            text: "1"
            background_color: [5, 2.0, 1, 5]
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: [1, 0.1]
        Button:
            text: "2"
            background_color: [0, 1.5, 0, 1]
            font_size: 40
            size_hint: [1, 0.1]
        Label:
            text: ""
            size_hint: [1, 0.4]

""")

class Menu(Screen):
    pass

program = ScreenManager()
program.add_widget(Menu(name = "menu"))

class TimeboardApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return program        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TimeboardApp().run()
```

Comment: Значит не правильно указан путь к изображению!

Comment: Спасибо, я уже исправил, когда перешел на KivyMD